# Would using milk powder better than fresh milk when poaching?

Tags: fish, milk, poaching

I read this question - [What is the effect of poaching fish in milk?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/28996/what-is-the-effect-of-poaching-fish-in-milk) and was surprise that one can poach fish using milk.

However, I was wondering if the milk will be spoil if it is continuous being cooked? And also would it be better if milk powder is used instead of just fresh milk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poaching is a gentle process - the milk isn't boiling so there is no risk of it burning or the like. It will of course not spoil in the sense of it going off, that's a totally different process.

Fresh milk is better because, well, it's fresh. Powdered milk would probably work, but if you have fresh, use that.

Comment: Depending on how you look at it powdered milk is fresher than "fresh milk". Powdered milk is powdered within 12 to 24 hours after milking and then vacuum packed which makes it last a year or so. While "fresh milk" will most likely be at least 24 to 48 hours old depending where you live, and will only last a week. While powdered milk tastes odd when served as a plain drink, it works very well in cooking